# JHipster elasticsearch configuration for multiple cluster nodes

Tags: jhipster, elasticsearch-jest

I am developing a jhipster project with elasticsearch. As [Using Elasticsearch](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/) page describes, I used the spring.data.jest.uri property for production use as follows:

```
spring:
......... # omitted to keep short
    data:
        mongodb:
            uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
            database: PROJ1
        jest:
            uri: http://172.20.100.2:9200
```

What I want is, give more than one uri for elasticsearch because I have set up a 3-node cluster. If one node goes down, another alive node should be used. Is such a configuration possible and if possible how sould I do it?